# React-Native GDrive API "Error-> [AbortError: Aborted]"

Tags: react-native, google-drive-api

I'm using the *@robinbobin/react-native-google-drive-api-wrapper* for GDrive file access. I can sign in with the *@react-native-google-signin/google-signin* to get the access token. But when I try to access the google drive (tried `gdrive.files.list({})` and `gdrive.about.get('*')`), I always get the "**Error-> [AbortError: Aborted]**" with the "**LOG**" tag due to timeout.

> LOG  Error-> [AbortError: Aborted]

I've also tried the *RobinBobin/gdrivetest* project from https://github.com/RobinBobin/gdrivetest. Still got the same "**Error-> [AbortError: Aborted]**" message.

Any help is appreciated!

**Related Code:**

```
 // Signin configure
 GoogleSignin.configure({
  scopes: [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appfolder',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
  ],
});

// GDrive access
const gdrive = new GDrive();
gdrive.accessToken = (await GoogleSignin.getTokens()).accessToken;
gdrive.fetchCoercesTypes = true
gdrive.fetchRejectsOnHttpErrors = true
gdrive.fetchTimeout = 30000
console.log(await gdrive.about.get('*'));

// Tried this as well
let data = await gdrive.files.list({
  q: new ListQueryBuilder()
     .e('folderId', '1cU1OKC9K20DivHcdMeIhwMWGThIudLEB')
      .in('root', 'parents'),
})
```

**Google Drive API Setup:**

Enabled APIs:

```
Google Drive API        
App Engine Admin API                    
BigQuery API                    
BigQuery Migration API                  
BigQuery Storage API                    
Cloud Datastore API                 
Cloud Debugger API                  
Cloud Logging API                   
Cloud Monitoring API                    
Cloud Pub/Sub API                   
Cloud Resource Manager API                  
Cloud Runtime Configuration API                 
Cloud SQL                   
Cloud Storage                   
Cloud Storage API                   
Cloud Testing API                   
Cloud Trace API                 
FCM Registration API                    
Firebase App Distribution API                   
Firebase Cloud Messaging API                    
Firebase Dynamic Links API                  
Firebase Hosting API                    
Firebase Installations API                  
Firebase Management API                 
Firebase Remote Config API                  
Firebase Rules API                  
Google Cloud APIs                   
Google Cloud Storage JSON API                   
Identity Toolkit API                    
Mobile Crash Reporting API                  
Service Management API                  
Service Usage API                   
Token Service API
```

Comment: have you considered posting a  question on the github page for that rapper.

Comment: @DaImTo I will post the question to github as well. Thanks for suggestion.